# Installing ANTLR in Visual Studio 2012 (using Nuget)

Tags: antlr4

Can not to generation classes.
1. I have VS 2012 version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5
2. Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.7.2
After that I made all steps what were described in this guide:

https://riptutorial.com/antlr/example/24621/installing-antlr-in-visual-studio-2015--using-nuget-

Then I saved the project and run it, but classes were not generated.
What do I make wrong? Anybody can help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98TlI.png)

Comment: Also I have written the next command for pre-build event:
java -jar $(TargetDir)antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp Calculator.g4
Where TargetDir is variable of the path with antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar, but it didn't help me. I got an Error 1 The command "java -jar D:\DevExpress\ANTLR4\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Release\antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp Calculator.g4
" exited with code 1. ConsoleApplication1

Comment: So,does ANTLR4 generate Lexer.cs and Parser.cs in VS or not?

Comment: Just curious: why do you use such an old VS?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found solution. We need upload two Nuget packages.
ANTLR 4 Runtime (version 4.6.6) and ANTLR 4 Code Generation (version 4.6.0)
Delete all command like java -jar $(TargetDir)antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp Calculator.g4 from pre-build event. It doesn't to have any sence.
Than need to save project and build it.

I hope this will help somebody.